# Azure AD Registered App Web URI Resolution in HashiCorp Vault

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, uri, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

As part of our Azure AD and HashiCorp Vault OIDC single sign-on implementation, I have registered an application in our corporate Azure AD and provided a couple of allowed redirect URIs in my Terraform configuration that are along the lines of the following:

```
   allowed_redirect_uris="http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback"
   allowed_redirect_uris="https://{hostname.domain}:8200/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback"
```

The terraform configuration is provisioned via a GitLab CI/CD pipeline and manages to deploy successfully. However, when I then attempt to login into Vault via the UI (as shown below), I get a Microsoft Sign in error message pop-up which includes the following:

**AADSTS50011**: The redirect URI `'https://{hostname.domain}/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback` specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application '`{Azure Tenant Id}`'. Make sure the redirect..............

[image]

**Note**: The URL displayed in the error message is somehow missing the port number 8200 which is definitely included in our Azure AD registered app redirect uri configuration.

I have even tried stripping out this same port number from my Terraform code and redeployed, all in an attempt to keep it consistent with the expected URI given in the error message. Yet still, this has failed to yield the desired result and I keep getting the same error.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Networking redirects for Vault can be kind of tricky, and an error like this is not uncommon. This is even true for ingress on Kubernetes with Vault. Could you do a redirect for `/ui` also?

Answer (score 0):

Found one of the similar issue , please check if that could help .

According to discussion in [similar github hashicorp vault issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/13523#issuecomment-1000712896)

> **Vault’s OIDC provider should validate loopback IP redirect URIs
> according to [rfc8252 section-7.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.3)** : The authorization server MUST
> allow any port to be specified at the time of the request for loopback
> IP redirect URIs, to accommodate clients that obtain an available
> ephemeral port from the operating system at the time of the request.

This [Feat/OIDC loopback redirect dynamic by paladin-devops hashicorp/vault · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/13871/commits/4a66798d4df99e1ff578ad847927eea7bef6a4c9)
discusses to add checks on OIDC provider to allow for redirect URI to have a dynamic port in the redirect URI if the loopback address is included in the OIDC client

**References:**

1. [OIDC Provider Loopback Interface Redirection Issue- hashicorp vault (github)](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/13523)
2. [hashicorp vault/OIDC loopback redirect dynamic by paladin-devops
   GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/13871)